# Sort an array vertically not horizontally

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I wrote a code that gets the merged cells value in array. but the array is sorted horizontally (eg. A1, B1, C1, etc.). How can I modify it to sort Vertically? (A1, A2, A3, etc.)

```
Sub GetSelectedMergedCells()
    Dim selRange As Range
    Dim mergedCells As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cellArray() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim outputRange As Range
    
    Set selRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    ' Check if selection contains merged cells
    For Each mergedCells In selRange
        If mergedCells.MergeCells Then
            ReDim Preserve cellArray(i)
            cellArray(i) = mergedCells.Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next mergedCells
    
    ' Write the result to a new worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set outputRange = ws.Range("A1").Resize(i, 1)
    outputRange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cellArray)
    ws.Columns.AutoFit
    
    ' Display a message box
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following " & i & " merged cells were found:" & vbCrLf & Join(cellArray, vbCrLf)
    Else
        MsgBox "No merged cells were found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2019 or 365. You can use the **Sort** function to sort the array by column by setting the fourth parameter to true.

The parameters are:
SORT(array, [sort_index], [sort_order], [by_column])

How to use it is:

```
cellArray = WorksheetFunction.Sort(cellArray, 1, 1, True)
```

Comment: It worked but it is sorting like this (A1, A13, A117, etc.). Can it be sorted like this (A1, A2, A3,A4 etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

### List Merged Cells' Addresses

[image]

**Main**

```
Sub ListMergedCellsAddresses()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "List Merged Cells' Addresses"
    Const SCAN_BY_COLUMN As Boolean = True
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    
    Dim Data: Data = GetMergedCellsAddresses(srg, SCAN_BY_COLUMN)
    
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        MsgBox "No merged cells found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    ' Last Sheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    ' First Sheet:
    'Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=wb.Sheets(1))
    ' After Source:
    'Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
    ' Before Source:
    'Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=sws)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(UBound(Data, 1))
    
    With drg
        .Value = Data
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Merged cells' addresses listed in worksheet """ & dws.Name _
        & """!", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
 End Sub
```

**The Function**

```
Function GetMergedCellsAddresses( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ScanByColumn As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    If ScanByColumn Then
        Set srg = rg.Columns
    Else
        Set srg = rg.Rows
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim srrg As Range, cell As Range
    
    For Each srrg In srg
        For Each cell In srrg.Cells
            If cell.MergeCells Then
                dict(cell.Address(0, 0)) = Empty
            End If
        Next cell
    Next srrg
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dict.Count
    
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim Key, r As Long
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        Data(r, 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    GetMergedCellsAddresses = Data
    
End Function
```